# Stop NStimer when touches moved out of touched object

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have some problems with my app. So, I need to stop NStimer when finger moved out of touched object (button). So there is a code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

        if ([testButton.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]) {

            timer = 60;
            time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        } else if (![testButton.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]){
            [time invalidate];
        }
    } 

     }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [time invalidate];
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what's the error, or problem?

Comment: What's the error? Also, add time = nil; after [time invalidate];

Comment: Ok, when I move finger to another object the timer don't stop

Comment: Be sure that you are not sending your timer multiple times.

Comment: Is time typed as a strong object?

Comment: Check for time and invalidate before calling this as well, time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`touchesBegan` event executes when you press your finger on the screen. If you move your finger, `touchesMoved` is called for every move, and when you lift your finger, `touchEnd` is called.

So, basically you should add code for testing if desired button is touched to the `touchMoved` method.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![testButton.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]){
        [time invalidate];
        time = nil;
    }
}
```